# WP ACF plugin max_vars issue (PHP suhosin)

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, advanced-custom-fields, suhosin

I have problem with Advanced Custom Fields plugin in my Wordpress site. When I tried to add the 15th field WP redirects me to posts instead of saving the field.
It's server issue beacuse I've cloned the WP with database to another server and it works fine.

I've found this [tutorial](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/limit-number-fields/) but on mentioned server they haven't got the `PHP suhosin` support, and they don't know how to solve this.

Do anybody knows any workaround to solve this issue ? I've tried both php.ini and .htaccess methods.

Answer (score 1):

**Overview**
It is ordinarily misconceived that there's a limit on the amount of fields you'll increase a field cluster. ACF doesn't contain a limit, however, your server will contain a limit on what percentage variables are often used on every page.

To ingeminate, ACF isn't limiting the amount of fields you'll save, instead, the server is just terminating the save method before ACF will end it’s job.

The most common answer is to extend your max_vars setting. {this is|this is often|this are often} a PHP setting that determines what percentage variables can be employed in one page load. By increasing this limit, you'll enable ACF to finish it’s job.

**php.ini**
You can increase this setting by making a *php.ini* file. This file could exist already on your server, however it's possibly you'll have to be compelled to produce this yourself. Please note that your internet host are happy to assist you produce this file, therefore please contact them if you run into any difficulties.
In the php.ini file, you'll add this to raise your limit to 3000

```
max_input_vars = 3000
suhosin.get.max_vars = 3000
suhosin.post.max_vars = 3000
suhosin.request.max_vars = 3000
```

**htaccess**
If you are doing not want to make a php.ini file, it's additionally doable to update these settings via the .htaccess go in the basis of your web site folder. This methodology is less complicated, but it's going to not work on all servers. Please contact them if you run into any difficulties.

```
php_value max_input_vars 3000
php_value suhosin.get.max_vars 3000
php_value suhosin.post.max_vars 3000
php_value suhosin.request.max_vars 3000
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I've tried this methods from tutorial. The problem is that on the server they haven't got "suhosin" so i must use other method if any exist.

Answer (score 0):

already found a simple workaround.

I've splitted all 84 fields into 6 groups each of 14 fields and everything works fine now.